# Structuring an MINLP solver

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, minlp, coin-or, concert, nlp

Folks, I am working on a project in which I have to code some C++ algorithms for smooth MINLPs.
Such algorithms are Extended Cutting Plane, Extended Supporting Hyperplane, and Outer Approximation. I am planning to use some MILP solver (for solving the master problem) along with its callback functionality (for adding cuts from the slave problems).

Therefore, I am trying to choose the most suitable option for my situation.
Below I listed such options in a table.
So far I have listed some requirements the MILP solver must have (1st column), and the corresponding functions (remaining columns) in two solvers, the Coin-OR B&C, and the CPLEX.

I placed the "?" character in the cells I do not know the proper information.
I am looking for the remaining information necessary to fill this table.
I would like to know if someone has worked with MINLP before, and
if has some answers for filling this table.
Also, any recommendations of others solvers are very welcome.

| Requirements | CBC-COIN-OR |  | CPLEX Concert |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | Functions | References | Functions | References |
| Get inequalities | getNumRows() | https://www.coin-or.org/Doxygen/CoinAll/class_cbc_model.html#40e058a76208364a573dc109586bd208 | IloConstraintArray | https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/icos/12.9.0?topic=c-iloconstraintarray-1 |
| Get inequality sense | getRowSense() | https://www.coin-or.org/Doxygen/CoinAll/class_cbc_model.html#9cf311df9ca4dd9165a925a780f73d59 | IloConstraintArray.getImpl() | https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/icos/12.9.0?topic=c-ilonumexprarg-1#method_getImpl |
| Get inequality LHS | ? | ? | IloConstraintArray.getImpl() | https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/icos/12.9.0?topic=c-ilonumexprarg-1#method_getImpl |
| Get inequality RHS | getRightHandSide() | https://www.coin-or.org/Doxygen/CoinAll/class_cbc_model.html#10f1678372ac83e3c84ec0173382c49a | IloConstraintArray.getImpl() | https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/icos/12.9.0?topic=c-ilonumexprarg-1#method_getImpl |
| Get non-linear inequalities | ? | ? | ? | ? |
| Get convex inequalities | ? | ? | ? | ? |
| Get variables | getNumCols() | https://www.coin-or.org/Doxygen/CoinAll/class_cbc_model.html#5d010c66439040cc41f325e403ac455d | IloNumVarArray | https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/icos/12.9.0?topic=c-ilonumvararray-1 |
| Get integer variables | numberIntegers() integerType(int I) isContinuous(int colIndex) isBinary(int colIndex) isInteger(int colIndex) IsIntegerNonBinary(int colIndex) | https://www.coin-or.org/Doxygen/CoinAll/class_cbc_model.html#46b35008e5dde744de7861a456597888 | ? | ? |
| Get non-integer variables | numberIntegers() integerType(int I) isContinuous(int colIndex) isBinary(int colIndex) isInteger(int colIndex) IsIntegerNonBinary(int colIndex) | https://www.coin-or.org/Doxygen/CoinAll/class_cbc_model.html#46b35008e5dde744de7861a456597888 | ? | ? |
| Get variables UB | getColUpper() GetCbcColUpper () | https://www.coin-or.org/Doxygen/CoinAll/class_cbc_model.html#e029873f5a7b4aef3df4ad30be929e1f | IloRangeArray | https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/icos/12.9.0?topic=c-ilorangearray-1 |
| Get variables LB | GetColLower () GetCbcColLower () | https://www.coin-or.org/Doxygen/CoinAll/class_cbc_model.html#cfa9192b32bde2d710e85deb71bce52b | IloRangeArray | https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/icos/12.9.0?topic=c-ilorangearray-1 |
| Read LP file | readLp | https://www.coin-or.org/Doxygen/CoinAll/class_osi_clp_solver_interface.html#d13f9e98ebaec68ce028d5aec95e6c38 | importModel(IloModel & m, const char * filename) | https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/icos/12.9.0?topic=c-ilocplex-3#method_importModel |
| Read MPS file | readMps | https://www.coin-or.org/Doxygen/CoinAll/class_osi_clp_solver_interface.html#edd68d7b3e54507a1afa0df0712f76d1 | importModel(IloModel & m, const char * filename) | https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/icos/12.9.0?topic=c-ilocplex-3#method_importModel |

Thank you very much for the attention, best regards.

Comment: For things like get inequality sense, get RHS etc., are you looking to fetch those things from the original model (before presolving, adding cuts etc.), at the root node (after doing those things and any other changes), or at arbitrary nodes in the search tree?

Comment: Thanks for the comment @prubin. Given the inequalities defining the search space, in an arbitrary B&B node, I must be able to obtain these inequalities, i.e. L and R-HS, and their senses. To have a better understanding, take a look at bullet (2) of section 3.2 on page 5 from https://doi.org/10.1007/s11081-018-9411-8.

Comment: I'm not sure direct access to the node LPs is available in the CPLEX C++ API. I know it is not available in Java. My impression is that the only API that lets you inspect node LPs is the C API (but I might be wrong).

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I'd not use terms like slave in the 21st century. For me it's the main problem & sub-problems.
Most modern solvers like Gurobi can approach MINLP using decomposition methods. The following links may be of some help.
[Gurobi](https://support.gurobi.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/11466556605713-MINLP-solver),
[API Details](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/10.0/refman/cpp_api_details.html),
[C++](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/10.0/refman/cpp_api_overview.html#sec:C++),
[Attributes](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/10.0/refman/attributes.html#sec:Attributes)

Comment: Thank you very much.